# Multiple pie graphs highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am using 3d pie graphs from highcharts. Especially I have a table that in each column (4 column) I display a graph. I have this situation:
[image]

As you can see the cell dont have the same distance of width. 
The HTML -javascript code is(to display one graph that is the same of 3 other):

```
 Highcharts.chart('container1', {
    chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
          alpha:70,
            beta: 0
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },

    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: false,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            size:100,
            depth: 15,


               dataLabels: {
               textOverflow:'none',
                      enabled: true,
                    color:'black',
                    connectorColor:'transparent',
                    format:'{point.percentage:.1f}%',
                    distance:-30,
                    style:{
                    textShadow:false}
                },
                showInLegend: false
        }
    },
 series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'ΑΞΚΟΙ - ΑΝΘΣΤΕΣ',

        data: [   
            ['Παρόντες',   <?php
               while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
                   while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)){
                    $row3['COUNT(*)']=$row2['COUNT(*)'] - $row1['COUNT(*)'];
                    echo $row3['COUNT(*)'];

                    }
                }?>],
            ['Απόντες', <?php


                      while( $row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res3)){

                    echo $row3['COUNT(*)'];

                    }

                    ?>]
]  
    }]
});
```

I display the charts into div. So the HTML code is:

```
<tr class='print_dynamometer'>
<td class='print_dynamometer' colspan='5'><div id='container1' style='width: 150px; height: 150px; margin:0 auto; left:0px top:0px;'><div></td>
<td class='print_dynamometer' colspan='5'><div id='container2' style='width: 150px; height: 150px; margin:0 auto; left:0px top:0px;'><div></td>
<td class='print_dynamometer' colspan='5'><div id='container3' style='width: 150px; height: 150px; margin:0 auto; left:0px top:0px;'><div></td>
<td class='print_dynamometer' colspan='5'><div id='container4' style='width: 150px; height: 150px; margin:0 auto; left:0px top:0px;'><div></td>
</tr>
```

CSS code is:

```
table.print_dynamometer{border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:left; margin:0px auto; width:680px; height:auto;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;padding:2px; background-color:white;}
th.print_dynamometer,td.print_dynamometer,tr.print_dynamometer{border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:left; margin:0px auto; width:575; height:auto;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;padding:2px; background-color:white; white-space:nowrap;}
```

I want the columns have the same distance in width!

Comment: did you try to add  overflow: hidden;  to the divs?

Comment: You really need to use a `table` ?

Comment: Yes its important to use a table

Comment: @posoppis unfortunately overflow:hidden dont work! Any other idea about how each column have the same width?

Comment: your table's got 680px in width but your charts are together only 600px. also why are th/tr/td formatted like that: width:575; ?

Comment: also please check if there are cells in other rows that make the columns stretch (eg too long text or something like that)

Comment: Maybe this is at fault. Anyway. Thank you after all

Comment: @posoppis i did the changes that you idicated me but the problem remain. The dimensions of column's width is not the same

Comment: sorry, I don't know any more solutions. maybe you can figure it out on your own by using the devtools

Comment: Any other solution from someone else?